# Which noun is it?

Tags: riddle

Which **noun** am I describing?

- Bad feelings enforce it
- It's too common on the internet
- Your parents won't teach it to you

Comment: Whatever the opposite of "manners" is :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be?

> cursing

Because:

> Bad feelings make you curse. Way too much foul language on the Internet. And most parents seem reluctant to teach their children to curse.

Or am I missing the whole point of this riddle?

Comment: Cursing is not the word I searched, though the one I described... 
Therefore technically it's correct :)


This was too easy... 

If you get the word I searched I mark the answer as correct.

Comment: @TobiasPeter Profanity? And is this the correct train of thought?

Comment: no :/ go on :) you're near

Comment: @TobiasPeter swear? :D running out of words here...

Comment: haha no neither... It's a noun... Lemme help: First Char is 'V'

Comment: :D vituperation?

Comment: nope :/ .... there aren't much more haha so you'll get it soon

Comment: Btw "swear" is also a noun (not only a verb). It's short for swear-word. Vulgarity?

Comment: Exactly, you got it! Thx for teaching me the 'swear'-thing :) English isn't my mother-language obviously haha